# Form scrolling to top on click of radio button or checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, scroll

I have created a form using QuForm on: http://create.mindview.us/create

***(Scroll down and select the standard package and the form will pop-up)***

When ever I check a radio button or checkbox the page **scrolls to the top**.

I would like the form to stay at the field that is being clicked and not scroll.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be great if you show what you have tried. Would it be possible for you to provide your code? Then, someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for the welcoming. I honestly don't know what code snippets to post here. I've been trying to track down the event that is causing the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I still encounter this problem with Quform when using popup forms.

The solution for me was changing from Fancybox 2 to **Fancybox 3** in `Quform-settings > Tweaks & Troubleshooting > Popup script`